# jQuery set CSS style of Class by using Data attribute

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I've this elements

```
<div class="circle-200" data-image="pic1" ></div>
<div class="circle-200" data-image="pic2" ></div>
<div class="circle-200" data-image="pic3" ></div>
```

after the page is loaded i would that the data-image values became the backgound-image of corresponding circle-200 class

Is it possible, using jQuery, do such a thing ?

```
$('.circle-200').css('background-image', "url('"+$(this).data('img')+"')");
```

Comment: jQuery will take all `data-*` attributes and add them to the data for the elements. This means that you can access the `data-image` attribute via `$(selector).data("image")` (not `img`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [.css( propertyName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

> A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

Also note it should be `image` not `img`

```
$('.circle-200').css('background-image', function() {
    return "url('" + $(this).data('image') + "')");
});
```

```js
$('.circle-200').css('background-image', function() {
  return "url('" + $(this).data('image') + "')"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle-200" data-image="pic1">pic1</div>
<div class="circle-200" data-image="pic2">pic2</div>
<div class="circle-200" data-image="pic3">pic3</div>
```